# Proper usage of Express' res.render() and res.redirect()

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, render

I am using a `res.redirect('page.ejs');` and on my browser I get the message:

> Cannot GET /page.ejs

I have not declared this in my routes file in the style of :

```
app.get('/page', function(req, res) {
        res.render('page.ejs');
    });
```

Should this be included in order for the `res.redirect()` to work?

When I do not use `res.redirect()` but `res.render()`, even if I have not the `app.get()` code, it still works.

Comment: EJS templates need to be rendered, the client won't do that. Just use `res.render`, don't use `res.redirect` at all here

Comment: If i use res.render() should i use the app.get() code?

Comment: If you want the user to see the rendered `page.ejs` when they visit `/page`, use `app.get('/page', function(req, res) {
        res.render('page.ejs');
    });`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

so to understand this, let's look at what each of these methods do.

```
res.redirect('page.ejs');
// or, more correctly, you're redirecting to an *endpoint* 
// (not a page. the endpoint will render a *page*) so it should be: 
res.redirect('/page');
```

this will tell express to redirect your request to the `GET /page.ejs` endpoint. An endpoint is the express method you described above:

```
app.get('/page', function(req, res) {
    res.render('page.ejs');
});
```

since you don't have that endpoint defined it will not work. If you do have it defined, it will execute the function, and the `res.render('page.ejs')` line will run, which will return the `page.ejs` file. You could return whatever you want though, it can be `someOtherPage.ejs` or you can even return json `res.json({ message: 'hi' });`

---

```
res.render('page.ejs');
```

this will just respond to the client (the front-end / js / whatever you want to call it) with the `page.ejs` template, it doesn't need to know whether the other endpoint is present or not, it's returning the `page.ejs` template itself.

so then, it's really up to you what you want to use depending on the scenario. Sometimes, one endpoint can't handle the request so it defers the request to another endpoint, which theoretically, knows how to handle the request. In that case `redirect` is used.

hope that makes sense and clarifies your confusion

(I'm not an expert on the inner-workings of express, but this is a high-level idea of what it's doing)

Answer (score 1):

You should do `res.redirect('/page')`